# Perforce: 'remove from workspace' from command line?

Tags: shell, perforce, workspace

The [p4v Perforce GUI client](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4v.html) has an 'Actions > Remove from Workspace' menu command which removes all files from the workspace that are under version control and were not opened for edit or delete.

This functionality only seems to be available from the GUI client, I can't find any corresponding command in the ever growing list shown by `p4 help commands`.

I thought of using `p4 where`, `p4 files` and some list filtering, but that doesn't seem trivial, so before I go about creating a script, does anyone have a better idea ?

Comment: I always thought that "Remove from Workspace" was badly named, since it could also imply removing the file/folder from your client spec.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Specifying a revision of either `#none` or `#0` will remove the files:

```
p4 sync //depot/project/...#none
p4 sync //depot/project/...#0
```

Use the -f switch to force removal of the files even if they are writeable (it won't affect files that are checked out, however):

```
p4 sync -f //depot/project/...#0
```

Comment: thank you very much guys, I'm so glad I asked here first! :-)

Comment: i was looking all over for this

Answer (score 10):

```
p4 sync ...#none
```

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to find GUI equivalent commands (p4 CLI commands) 
is to look at log tab in P4V. When we take any action on P4V GUI, 
the "log" tab shows the corresponding P4 CLI command being executed.