# Reverting unshelved files in perforce

Tags: perforce, revert

I have unshelved a cl that contained an 'add' file called foo.txt. When i revert that changelist the foo.txt disappears from my workspace but stays on my hdd.

```
p4 unshelve -f -s $A -c default :: unshelving add foo.txt
p4 revert -c default //MY_WORKSPACE/... :: foo.txt is reverted
p4 opened -C MY_WORKSPACE :: shows none
```

When i open the workspace i still can see the foo.txt.

is there a way to delete the added file ?
(Except the obvious of deleting it manually)

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with unshelving.  Your question is really about reverting *added* files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perforce: 'remove from workspace' from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314848/perforce-remove-from-workspace-from-command-line)

Comment: @raven This has nothing to do with 'remove from workspace'. This is about what happens to the local file, after `p4 add` followed by `p4 revert`. (With `shelve`, `unshelve` thrown in to complicate matters).

Comment: I see now.  I withdraw my close vote.

Answer (score 3):

Running the revert command with `-w` flag will delete any files marked for add during the revert (see [p4_revert docs](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_revert.html))

`p4 revert -w [file specification]`

e.g.,
`p4 revert -w -c default //MY_WORKSPACE/...` 
(foo.txt is deleted from disk, then reverted)

Comment: This a great solution! Note that 'revert -w' requires that your server be at version 2013.2 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

Such behaviour is by design.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/04_files.html

> **Discarding changes (reverting)**
>
> To remove an open file from a
> changelist and discard any changes you made, issue the p4 revert
> command. When you revert a file, Perforce restores the last version
> you synced to your workspace. **If you revert a file that is open for
> add, the file is removed from the changelist but is not deleted from
> your workspace.**

Answer (score 0):

Once you've reverted the file add in Perforce, I think you can just delete them from the disk - Perforce has forgotten about them entirely.

Comment: Shouldn't the revert function do that?

Comment: @Twisted: The thinking is probably that it'd be dangerous for the `revert` command to do that since if you do it by accident, you're likely to lose a significant amount of work.  (Arguably they could add a command-line option to `revert` to do it, though.)

Comment: Well, it's time to revise my shell scripting knowledge.

Comment: No, Perforce has not forgotten about them entirely.  It knows that you have them in your workspace.  If you delete them outside of Perforce, they won't appear again during a sync operation because Perforce thinks you already have them.  You would have to do a forced sync.  [Use Perforce to delete them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2318537/4228) so as not to confuse the server.

Comment: @raven That would apply to files already submitted to the repository. But I don't think that applies to files after `p4 add` `p4 revert`. What version would it sync, since there is no revision in the repository?

Comment: @DouglasLeeder: You're right.  My bad.  I completely misinterpreted the question.